# How to make Android Splash Screen Fullscreen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, splash-screen

This is my code. I am following a tutorial on Youtube. When I use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` the screen does not show the splash screen and shows a blank screen instead. My code is as the following.

```
<activity
   android:name="com.nowate.customerapp.activity.SplashActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: The block of code that you shared with us is from Android Manifest. Please, share your "SplashActivity" code and the xml of SplashActivity layout so we'll be able to help!

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to add a splash screen to your app. It doesn't take any fixed time to display it because it is showing while the app really loads.

1. Declare a new theme in `styles.xml`:

```
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
 </style>
```

2. Set the theme in `AndroidManifest` to your launcher activity (don't create a new activity just for a splash screen):

```
<activity
   android:name="com.nowate.customerapp.activity.MainActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

3. In your MainActivity in the `onCreate()` method set the original theme befor setting the layout:

```
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

4. Example of splash screen drawable ("ic_loading" is a vector):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading"/>
</layer-list>
```